Not able to find EventSettings Metadata API type to set retention period for the event logs
I am following this documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_em_download_elf.htm&release=250&type=5
I have enabled Retain event log files in Event Monitoring Settings.
I am not able to follow the next step:
Then, to specify the number of days to retain your data, use the eventLogRetentionDuration field on the EventSettings Metadata API type.
Not able to find EventSettings Metadata API type.
Checked on the Event Monitoring Settings page and in Custom Metadata Types, but not able to find.
Does anyone have any idea how to set value in eventLogRetentionDuration field?

You will have to retrieve the "EventSettings" xml, using vs-code.
You can use below manifest as per the documentation or try the sfdx command to pull the settings.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <types>
     <members>Event</members>
     <name>Settings</name>
   </types>
   <version>61.0</version>
</Package>

Once you download the xml, you will be able to adjust the "eventLogRetentionDuration" field. You will have to redeploy the xml.
Not sure why Salesforce doesn't have this field updated on Metadata API Documentation.

I am able to retrieve the meta xml. I added the field eventLogRetentionDuration in meta.xml with value 15 and tried to deploy. But getting error force-app\main\default\settings\Event.settings-meta.xml  Property 'eventLogRetentionDuration' not valid in version 59.0

As the error suggests, its not available in v59. You might need to bump the version to v61 and try.

It worked with v61. When I updated the package.xml with version 61, I got the Event.settings-meta.xml with field eventLogRetentionDuration. Then I updated the field value and deployed using package.xml and it worked successfully. Can you please update the xml version in answer to 61 so I can accept the answer.

Updated manifest xml above.
